# How to absolute position after dynamical size block?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this blocks, located in the order A, B, C:

[image: blocks grid]

Blocks "A" and "C" `position: absolute`. I need display block "C" after block "A", but the height of the block "A" may very, and I can not use the property `top`. Here is an example of code:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.block-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.block-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}

.block-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;    
  background: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skriming/xn47v51k/

Comment: Can i change position on like block b then block a and block c in html ?

Comment: No, this is the problem.

Comment: Use js to find block `a` height, and add this value to block `c`s top

Comment: I can not do it by css?

Comment: Can the position absolute of A and C be changed ?

Comment: @izorgor Yes of course

Comment: Is this what you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/g2nm914y/1/

Comment: @HiddenHobbes thx! can you create answer?

Comment: No problem @skriming, because the question is closed I wont be able to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your CSS with below one:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
}

.block-1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.block-2 {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
}

.block-3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution but it combines css + jquery

I added float left to the B block

```
.block-2{float: left}
```

and top position to the C block with jQuery

```
var aHeight = $(".block-1").height();
$(".block-3").css("top",aHeight);
```

If you can`t use jquery for some reason let me know.

Comment: You didn't close last line of code, but here ya go https://jsfiddle.net/ywku3hvg/